# Average pooling with window over variable length sequences

Tags: python, tensorflow, moving-average, pooling

I have a tensor `in` of shape (batch_size, features, steps) and want to get an output tensor `out` of the same shape by average pooling over the time dimension (steps) with a window size of `2k+1`, that is:

```
out[b,f,t] = 1/(2k+1) sum_{t'=t-k,...,t+k} in[b,f,t']
```

For time steps where there are no `k` preceding and succeeding time steps, I only want to calculate the average on the existing time steps.

However, the sequences in the tensor have variable length and are padded with zeros accordingly, I have the sequence lengths stored in another tensor (and could e.g. create a mask with them).

- I know I can use [`out = tf.nn.avg_pool1d(in, ksize=2k+1, strides=1, padding="SAME", data_format="NCW")`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/nn/avg_pool1d) that performs my described pooling-operation, however it does not understand that my sequences are padded with zero and does not allow me to pass a mask with the sequence lengths.
- There also is [`tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalAveragePooling1D), but that layer always pools over the entire sequence and doesn't allow me to specify a window size.

How can I perform this operation **with masking and a window size**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such operation in TensorFlow. However, one can use a combination of two unmasked pooling operations, here written in pseudocode:

1. Let `seq_mask` be a [sequence mask](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask) of shape (batch_size, time)
2. Let `in_pooled` be a the tensor `in` with unmasked average pooling
3. Let `seq_mask_pooled` be the tensor `seq_mask` with unmasked average pooling with the same pool size
4. Obtain the tensor `out` as follows: Every element of `out`, where the sequence mask is `0`, should also be `0`. Every other element is obtained by dividing `in_pooled` through `seq_mask_pooled` element wise (not that the element of `seq_mask_pooled` is never `0` if the element of `seq_mask` is not).

The tensor `out` can e.g. be calculated using [`tf.math.divide_no_nan`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/divide_no_nan).